# My iOS simulator doesn't work from the root account, but works from the user's accounts

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, osx-lion, ios-simulator, root

When running from the root account only shows a black screen iOS simulator.
How to solve this problem?

UPD:

```
sh-3.2# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode 
com.apple.dt.instruments.backgroundinstruments: Already loaded
2012-05-20 21:57:32.871 Xcode[2538:107] ERROR: Failed to create an alert for ID "enabled" based on defaults: 1
2012-05-20 21:57:34.277 Xcode[2538:107] Error launching simulated application: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "iOS Simulator failed to install application." UserInfo=0x400e8b820 {NSLocalizedDescription=iOS Simulator failed to install application., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}
```

UPD:

Launching  the iOS simulator from the root account

Link: [pastebin.com/1Z8XxxcH](http://pastebin.com/1Z8XxxcH)

Screenshot: [imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/20120520101127pm.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/20120520101127pm.png)

Comment: Don't run the iOS simulator from the root account?

Comment: I need to work from the root account.